# Is "scroll" a valid CSS background attribute for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is **"scroll"** a valid value for the `background` CSS property in Internet Explorer?
So, does Internet Explorer ignore the following rule because of the presence of "scroll"?

```
background: url('/images/site.gif') scroll 0;
```

This question was asked because there was an argument between two other users over the validity of the scroll attribute for Internet Explorer.  Since I myself didn't know if it was a valid attribute, I decided to post the question, and told the 2 of them to just follow the post.  But, this is Stack Overflow, so of course my question is stupid / irrelavant / down voted.  That begs the question, why is an answer to a stupid question up-voted?

Comment: You have a colon after `no-repeat`. I'd try to remove it first.

Comment: This question originated from [comments elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886074/background-property-doesnt-work-in-ie/12886144#comment17449267_12886144).  I don't think this is a proper use of the site.

Comment: thank you. it was not supposed to be there.  This is the way the code should be.

Comment: Ok Let me edit it.  It's a legit question.

Comment: Actually, it's an exact duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886074/background-property-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: NO it is not!  Its asking if it's a vaild property. Read the message.

Comment: Hey Eric, I hear that there's a discussion that led up to this question. I think context is important to help other readers understand the problem. You think you could edit and add some background about what's going on? I think Rob W got you off to a good start with his edits, but I'd hate to see this question continue to get closed and reopened just because of some fixable, missing context. Good luck! :) Looking forward to seeing the final result!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a valid property (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-attachment)). But since you don't believe the documentation, the only way to convince you is to show a screenshot. `scroll` is a valid property of `background-attachment` (which is included in the shorthand for `background`). In fact, it's the default value.

To proof this, we read the value of `document.body.currentStyle.backgroundAttachment`. It's even supported in IE6!

[image: javascript:alert(document.body.currentStyle.backgroundAttachment)]

In your initial comment, you said *"that is background-attachment: Not background."*. So, taken that you still do not believe the documentation, I'll show yet another proof:

1. Assume that `fixed` is not a valid value for the `background` shorthand.
2. Then we derive that `background-attachment` is not included in the shorthand, because we know from the top part of this answer that `"fixed"` is a valid value of `background-attachment`.
3. So, if we use `body {background: url('/favicon.ico') fixed 0;}`, then `alert(document.body.currentStyle.backgroundAttachment);` should display "scroll", because it is the default value of `background-attachment` *and* we assumed that `background-attachment` is not supported by the background short-hand.
4. But the alert shows "fixed" ( the page in the screenshot is http://jsfiddle.net/Nvfmt/ ).
   [image: alerts fixed]
5. **Contradiction**. So we conclude that "scroll" is a valid value for `background`.

Comment: that is background-attachment:   Not background:

Comment: I asked to see the property for background:  Specifically background: I can't find it anywhere online.

Comment: @EricLeroy I have updated my answer with an additional proof, to counter your first comment.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I posted the exact refrence link in the question incase anyone else gets as confused as I was. :)   Thanks again for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

There is background-attachment: scroll, if that is what you mean, it's the default value of the property.

Omitting it produces the same result
http://jsfiddle.net/FKDer/

Comment: So what about background: scroll.   Would that cause an error?

Comment: @Eric: `background:` is just an easy way to specify most/all background properties at once.  If `scroll` is valid in one place, it should be valid in the other (assuming you put it in the right place).